# Bigquery/SQL Gets value for one column only and keeps other column NULL

Tags: mysql, join, google-bigquery, left-join

I got the below 2 tables:

1st table, Segment_info

| BookingID | SegmentID | PassengerID | SSRCode | SSRCreatedUTC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 371 | 251 | WCI | 2023-04-07 00:53:00.407000 UTC |
| 123 | 371 | 251 | MCI | 2023-04-07 03:20:07.547000 UTC |
| 123 | 371 | 251 | PB20 | 2023-04-07 00:52:19.107000 UTC |
| 123 | 371 | 251 | AB20 | 2023-04-08 06:58:54.950000 UTC |

The 2nd table, Baggage_info

| RecordLocator | BookingID | SegmentID | PassengerID | BaggageID | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 123 | 371 | 251 | 621 | 1 |
| ABC | 123 | 371 | 251 | 154 | 18 |
| ABC | 123 | 371 | 251 | 622 | 20 |

I want to map Baggage_Info to Segment_info based on the following rules.

1. When there are SSRCode equals to either ‘AB20’, ‘AB25’, ‘AB30’ or ‘AB40’, maps the baggage_info with the same SegmentID first
2. If there are no SSRCode equals to either ‘AB20’, ‘AB25’, ‘AB30’ or ‘AB40’,  but either ‘PB20’, ‘PB25’, ‘PB30’ or ‘PB40’ are shown, maps the baggage_info to the earliest SSRCreatedUTC with the same SegmentID
3. If the above 2 conditions do not meet and there are SSRCode equals to either ‘WCI’ or ‘MCI’, maps the baggage_info to the earliest SSRCreatedUTC with the same SegmentID

Hence I write the below query:

```
WITH 

segment_info AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SegmentID ORDER BY
      CASE WHEN SSRCode IN ('AB20', 'AB25', 'AB30', 'AB40') THEN 1
      WHEN SSRCode = 'PB40' THEN 2
      WHEN SSRCode = 'PB30' THEN 3
      WHEN SSRCode = 'PB25' THEN 4
      WHEN SSRCode = 'PB20' THEN 5
      WHEN SSRCode IN ('WCI', 'MCI') THEN 6
      ELSE 7 END,
      SSRCreatedUTC ASC
    ) AS rn
  FROM
    `Segment_Info`
),

combined_segment_baggage AS (SELECT

    BI.RecordLocator,

    SI.BookingID,
    SI.SegmentID,
    SI.PassengerID,
    BI.BaggageID,

    BI.Weight AS BaggageWeight,
    SI.SSRCode,
    SI.SSRCreatedUTC
FROM
  segment_info SI
LEFT JOIN
  `dml-prod.ADS_GOP_SNT.Baggage_Info` BI ON SI.SegmentID = BI.SegmentID AND SI.rn = 1)
```

From the above query, the query result will look like below

| RecordLocator | BookingID | SegmentID | PassengerID | BaggageID | BaggageWeight | SSRCode | SSRCreatedUTC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | 123 | 371 | 251 | NULL | NULL | WCI | 2023-04-07 00:53:00.407000 UTC |
| NULL | 123 | 371 | 251 | NULL | NULL | MCI | 2023-04-07 03:20:07.547000 UTC |
| NULL | 123 | 371 | 251 | NULL | NULL | PB20 | 2023-04-07 00:52:19.107000 UTC |
| ABC | 123 | 371 | 251 | 621 | 1 | AB20 | 2023-04-08 06:58:54.950000 UTC |
| ABC | 123 | 371 | 251 | 154 | 18 | AB20 | 2023-04-08 06:58:54.950000 UTC |
| ABC | 123 | 371 | 251 | 622 | 20 | AB20 | 2023-04-08 06:58:54.950000 UTC |

However, I want each row of the data contains the related RecordLocator and other column keeps in NULL

Expected result:

| RecordLocator | BookingID | SegmentID | PassengerID | BaggageID | BaggageWeight | SSRCode | SSRCreatedUTC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 123 | 371 | 251 | NULL | NULL | WCI | 2023-04-07 00:53:00.407000 UTC |
| ABC | 123 | 371 | 251 | NULL | NULL | MCI | 2023-04-07 03:20:07.547000 UTC |
| ABC | 123 | 371 | 251 | NULL | NULL | PB20 | 2023-04-07 00:52:19.107000 UTC |
| ABC | 123 | 371 | 251 | 621 | 1 | AB20 | 2023-04-08 06:58:54.950000 UTC |
| ABC | 123 | 371 | 251 | 154 | 18 | AB20 | 2023-04-08 06:58:54.950000 UTC |
| ABC | 123 | 371 | 251 | 622 | 20 | AB20 | 2023-04-08 06:58:54.950000 UTC |

Could anyone help to generate the required Bigquery? Thanks!

Comment: There is only 1 row in SI with rn = 1 joined to 3 rows = 3 rows output with a relationship, but there are still another 3 rows where rn <> 1 so you get 6 rows but 3 of these will have NULL in recordselector because of teh rn=1 restriction. Using an inner join or reversing the from/join tables results in 3 rows https://dbfiddle.uk/j9DDqxX4